# At which path javac, jar etc., binaries in AWS Lambda environment?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment

We want to know where(at which path) javac, jar etc., tools in lambda environment, for use them to compile ".java" files to ".class" and construct ".jar" from AWS-Lambda in Python language through running CLI-commands.

Don't misunderstand my question, our requirement is to 
1. Generate Java source_code files from some rules_source
2. Then we need to compile these generated java-src and need to construct jar file
3. Finally store that in S3 BUCKET and allow user to download through another service.

Here with lambda alone we couldn't do 2nd step. So, we took EC2 instance to compile java-source generated and store back to S3.

Can anyone suggest serverless-solution for this scenario. Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to call [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) and find the path of an executable.

```
import subprocess
path = subprocess.check_output(["which", "javac"])
```

Comment: Thanks, But Javac  and Jar tools are not found in the environment of lambda